# Replacing input in search field with onclick-event does not update list

Tags: javascript, html

I have a search field that filters three different lists. I want an `onclick`-event that adds text to the search field, and replaces any other value there may be.

I'm able to do so but `onclick` doesn't update the lists unless I click on the search field and hit enter manually. Adding the `click()` event didn't help.

At the same time, hitting the `X` in the search field to clear the input doesn't update the lists neither.

What can I do?

```
<p onclick="document.getElementById('searchCombo').value = 'element 1'; document.getElementById('searchCombo').click()">Filter for: vitamins</p>

<p onclick="document.getElementById('searchCombo').value = 'element 2'; document.getElementById('searchCombo').click()">Filter for: drugs</p>

<p onclick="document.getElementById('searchCombo').value = 'element 3'; document.getElementById('searchCombo').click()">Filter for: medications</p>

<input type="search" id="searchCombo" placeholder="Search for combination...">

<ul ID="list1" class="combo">
    <li><a href="#">List 1 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 1 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 1 element 3</a></li>
    <li class="none">Nothing found in this category</li>
</ul>

<ul ID="list2" class="combo">
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 3</a></li>
    <li class="none">Nothing found in this category</li>
</ul>

<ul ID="list3" class="combo">
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 3</a></li>
    <li class="none">Nothing found in this category</li>
</ul>
```

This is the javascript:

```
<script>
    /* drug combo search */
    const select_all = (selector, selectee = document) =>
        Array.from(selectee.querySelectorAll(selector));

    const hide_item = item => item.style.display = 'none';
    const show_item = item => item.style.display = '';
    const item_text = item => item.textContent.toLowerCase();
    const compare = text => item => item_text(item).includes(text);
    const has_class = class_name => item => item.className.includes(class_name);
    const not_has_class = class_name => item => !has_class(class_name)(item);

    const filter_list = text => list => {
        let lis = select_all("li", list);
        let to_show = lis
            .filter(not_has_class('none'))
            .filter(compare(text));

        if (to_show.length === 0)
            to_show = lis.filter(has_class('none'));

        lis.forEach(hide_item);
        to_show.forEach(show_item);
    };

    const filter = (event) =>
        select_all(".combo").forEach(
            filter_list((event?.target?.value || '').toLowerCase())
        );

    document.getElementById('searchCombo').addEventListener("keyup", filter);

    filter();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some flexibility with the HTML, this would be my suggestion:

I think you don't need the a tags here if you don't want them as long as you move the `class="filter_to" data-filter_to_term="element 1"` on to the p tags.

```js
const select_all = (selector, selectee = document) =>
  Array.from(selectee.querySelectorAll(selector));

const hide_item = item => item.style.display = 'none';
const show_item = item => item.style.display = '';
const item_text = item => item.textContent.toLowerCase();
const compare = text => item => item_text(item).includes(text);
const has_class = class_name => item => item.className.includes(class_name);
const not_has_class = class_name => item => !has_class(class_name)(item);

const filter_list = text => list => {
  let lis = select_all("li", list);
  let to_show = lis
    .filter(not_has_class('none'))
    .filter(compare(text));

  if (to_show.length === 0)
    to_show = lis.filter(has_class('none'));

  lis.forEach(hide_item);
  to_show.forEach(show_item);
};

const search_box = document.getElementById('searchCombo');

const filter = (text) =>
  select_all(".combo").forEach(
    filter_list((text || '').toLowerCase())
  );

const set_filter = (text) => {
  search_box.value = text;
  filter(text);
};

const onclick_filter_to = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  set_filter(event.target.dataset.filter_to_term);
};

select_all(".filter_to").forEach(
  (element) => element.addEventListener("click", onclick_filter_to)
);

search_box.addEventListener("input", event => filter(event.target.value));

filter();
```

```html
<p><a href="#" class="filter_to" data-filter_to_term="element 1">Filter for: vitamins</a></p>

<p><a href="#" class="filter_to" data-filter_to_term="element 2">Filter for: drugs</a></p>

<p><a href="#" class="filter_to" data-filter_to_term="element 3">Filter for: medications</a></p>

<input type="search" id="searchCombo" placeholder="Search for combination...">

<ul ID="list1" class="combo">
    <li><a href="#">List 1 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 1 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 1 element 3</a></li>
    <li class="none">Nothing found in this category</li>
</ul>

<ul ID="list2" class="combo">
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 3</a></li>
    <li class="none">Nothing found in this category</li>
</ul>

<ul ID="list3" class="combo">
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 3</a></li>
    <li class="none">Nothing found in this category</li>
</ul>
```

It looks like replacing keyup with input might work for the cancel X button in Chrome (but I've not used that before).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo [Jsbin working demo](https://jsbin.com/toputipabo/edit?html,js,output)

HTML

```
<p id="filter1">Filter for: vitamins</p>
<p id="filter2">Filter for: drugs</p>
<p id="filter3">Filter for: medications</p>

<input type="search" id="searchCombo" placeholder="Search for combination...">

<ul ID="list1" class="combo">
    <li><a href="#">List 1 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 1 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 1 element 3</a></li>
    <li class="none">Nothing found in this category</li>
</ul>

<ul ID="list2" class="combo">
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 2 element 3</a></li>
    <li class="none">Nothing found in this category</li>
</ul>

<ul ID="list3" class="combo">
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3 element 3</a></li>
    <li class="none">Nothing found in this category</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
const select_all = (selector, selectee = document) =>
Array.from(selectee.querySelectorAll(selector));

const hide_item = item => item.style.display = 'none';
const show_item = item => item.style.display = '';
const item_text = item => item.textContent.toLowerCase();
const compare = text => item => item_text(item).includes(text);
const has_class = class_name => item => item.className.includes(class_name);
const not_has_class = class_name => item => !has_class(class_name)(item);

const filter_list = text => list => {
    let lis = select_all("li", list);
    let to_show = lis
        .filter(not_has_class('none'))
        .filter(compare(text));

    if (to_show.length === 0)
        to_show = lis.filter(has_class('none'));

    lis.forEach(hide_item);
    to_show.forEach(show_item);
};

const filter = (value) =>
    select_all(".combo").forEach(
        filter_list((value || '').toLowerCase())
    );

const searchCombo = document.getElementById('searchCombo')
searchCombo.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    filter(e.target.value)
});
//Trigger filter when search input field cancel is clicked
searchCombo.addEventListener("search", function(e) {
    filter('')
});

function trigger(value) {
    searchCombo.value = value;
    filter(value)
}
document.getElementById('filter1').addEventListener("click", function() {
    trigger('element 1')
});
document.getElementById('filter2').addEventListener("click", function() {
    trigger('element 2')
});
document.getElementById('filter3').addEventListener("click", function() {
    trigger('element 3')
});


filter();
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there no way to add the onclick-event in the HTML document without editing the javascript?